# Pandas reading concatenated jsons written by df.to_json(orient='split')

Tags: python, pandas

From my understanding, the "split" param is means to allow batches to be written.

E.g.

```
with io.open('sample_predictions_json_split.json', 'w') as out:
    for i in range(0, len(df), 3):
        out.write(df[i:i+3].to_json(orient='split'))
        out.write('\n')
```

This yeilds a file which looks like this:

```
{"columns":["A","B","C"],"index":[0,1,2],"data":[[0.7152170382,0.8430748346,0.1486081169],[0.7152170382,0.8430748346,0.1486081169],[0.7152170382,0.8430748346,0.1486081169]]}
{"columns":["A","B","C"],"index":[3,4,5],"data":[[0.7152170382,0.8430748346,0.1486081169],[0.7152170382,0.8430748346,0.1486081169],[0.7152170382,0.8430748346,0.1486081169]]}
{"columns":["A","B","C"],"index":[6,7,8],"data":[[0.7152170382,0.8430748346,0.1486081169],[0.7152170382,0.8430748346,0.1486081169],[0.7152170382,0.8430748346,0.1486081169]]}
```

The advantage here is that the file can be split by line and distributed to different servers for processing batches of data.

How do I read back all the data in to a single dataframe? `pd.read_json('sample_predictions_json_split', lines=True)` does not work as expected. I can of course just use a for loop with io, but I feel Pandas should have a way to do this.

Comment: Have not tried it but in the documentation it says read_json also takes in `orient` param, so identical `orient` should, as far as I understand, do the trick.

Comment: @dm2 I've tried `pd.read_json('sample_predictions_json_split', lines=True, orient='split')`, which seems logical, but that does not work either.